Not able to get bounding box and other fields from the Layout Parser service
I am trying to extract text from a PDF file using the Layout Parser Python SDK. I have copied and used the sample code from the docs. However I've noticed that the output does not contain all the information I would expect, particularly in the layout element (contained in the pages element) that contains the bounding box I'm interested in. Only the documentLayout element is populated with information. The pages element is empty, the response looks like:
{
  "documentLayout": <<only this element has data>>,
  "mimeType": "",
  "text": "",
  "textStyles": [],
  "pages": [],
  "entities": [],
  "entityRelations": [],
  "textChanges": [],
  "revisions": []
}

I've tried adding a field mask and added it to the documentai.ProcessRequest() call, but to no avail:
from google.protobuf import field_mask_pb2
field_mask = field_mask_pb2.FieldMask(
        paths=[
            "pages.Layout",
        ]
    )

How can I get the extracted elements from the PDF together with their bounding boxes?
